# No se pudo entrar en la carpeta tags:/

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hola a todos les quiero pedir ayuda ya que estoy en linux, mas especificamente en kde neon y cuando enciendo mi computadora me da este error:

```
Error kde plasma:
No se ha podido entrar en la carpeta tags:/
```

Fuera de eso no noto nada fuera de lo inusual pero alguien me podría decir que es ese error, porque se produce, si es importante y como puedo arreglarlo, quiero aclarar que esto me paso después de por accidente cambiar el propietario de algunas carpetas y ahora que ya esta todo bien me pasa este error. Desde ya gracias :) por cierto quiero aclarar que tengo la versión de kde neon por defecto que si no me equivoco es ubuntu
.

Comment: Corre esto en el terminal: balooctl purge Con eso se debería arreglar (a mi me pasaba cuando abría dolphin entre otras situaciones). Referencia: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=154&t=171518

Comment: Intente lo que dijiste, me salio esto `Deleted the index database`, ¿ese es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Fue lo que me salió a mí cuando lo corrí. Te sigue saliendo el error?

Comment: Si, ahora que abrí dolphin me dio otra vez ese error

Comment: ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Eso es lo que he visto en 3 o 4 sitios que hay que hacer. Hay un fix, podrías ver si tienes una versión que ya lo tenga aplicado: https://invent.kde.org/system/dolphin/-/commit/4d9ea4261a1f24e299595b897ea790eab1748fe9 A mi me funcionó hacer lo que puse en la respuesta.

Comment: En cuanto al link creo que ya tengo la version que lo tiene, intente con volver a poner `balooctl purge` pero me sigue diciendo `Deleted the index database`, no se si asi este bien o si lo tengo que ejecutar desde alguna carpeta espefíca

Comment: Me parece que tu Pregunta esta mal ubicada; si bien este foro es para resolver problemas de Programacion tu pregunta esta directamente relacionada a un problema de Sistema Operativo Linux; aun asi falta informacion ya que no indicas que DISTRO usas y hay una gran variacion entre versiones y DISTROS... te recomiendo que tu pregunta la lleves al sitio de https://superuser.com/ o https://askubuntu.com/ en donde tendrán una mejor recepción ... mientras tanto tu pregunta en este sitio es off topic., te recomendaria leer este articulo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent voy a tomar en cuenta el preguntar en esos foros, pero segun tengo entendido kde neon por defecto tiene ubuntu y no especifique que yo usara otra distro

Comment: Eso que argumentas es completamente incorrecto la Descripción de KDE NEON es la siguiente: ***The latest and greatest of KDE community software packaged on a rock-solid base.*** en español: ***El último y mejor software de la comunidad de KDE empaquetado sobre una base sólida.*** y ninguna de sus versiones indican que sean exclusivas para Ubuntu... No asumas que la comunidad sabe que tienes en tus manos... tus publicaciones deben incluir toda la informacion que tu consideres necesaria; mas toda la que te pida la comunidad.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent listo ya esta editada la pregunta, problema solucionado. Saludos

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, tomado del sitio oficial de KDE: _KDE neon is the intersection of these needs using a stable **Ubuntu long-term release** as its core_, es decir, deriva de Ubuntu.

Comment: @Triby si tienes toda la razón la lo comprobé en: https://neon.kde.org/faq pero no me fio de esto ... he visto software que inicial mente esta destinado para una plataforma y terminan diversificando el negocio ... y me ha tocado estrellarme con guías, tutoriales que no especifican para que plataforma van destinadas por que asumían que la plataforma era única ... y al parecer este software corre sobre ubuntu y kubuntu no se si se acepta otros flawors de Ubuntu ...

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, KDE Plasma es un excelente escritorio, lamentablemente, tiene algunos inconvenientes. En mi caso, obtenía un error en cada inicio de sesión referente a la tarjeta de sonido; me pasó tanto con KDE Neon, como con Kubuntu, pero no con Xero Linux (basado en Arch). Te toca decidir si puedes vivir con esos mensajes que no afectan el funcionamiento del sistema operativo o buscas otra distribución.

Comment: @Triby tienes razon, este error aunque es molesto puedo vivir con el :) aunque me gustaría arreglarlo en algun futuro

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, los sabores de Ubuntu son simplemente distribuciones con un escritorio diferente al oficial (Gnome), excepto Ubuntu Studio, que creo que también usa KDE Plasma como escritorio (igual que Kubuntu), pero incluye códecs y software de edición de fotos, video y música. Aunque es posible, no soy partidario de instalar dos o más escritorios en una distribución.

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, viendo que el problema parece derivar de índices de archivos (para búsquedas), tal vez el problema sea por el sistema de archivos usado al formatear cada partición, hay quienes recomiendan BTRFS para la partición del sistema y XFS para particiones de datos, pero me temo que será algo difícil de probar, porque sería necesario reinstalar.

Comment: por hay ley que se debía vaciar la base de datos ... de la aplicación y que esta al requerirla nuevamente la reconstruiría ... pero no se si sea tambien un tema de permisos y privilegios ... que pasa si ejecutas con un usuario que tipo root???